# Show any two matrices that commute with M also commute with eachother

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a proof where

$$M=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\;.$$

I’ve tried looking at it in terms of $A$ and $B$ like $AM=MA$ and $BM=MB$ but the snag is that I can’t really get rid of $M$ to make $A=B$ so I’m not sure if I have the complete wrong idea or if there is a completely different way of doing it.

Comment: Hint: You're not trying to show $A=B$ just that $AB = BA$. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let

$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\;.$$

Then

$$AM=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}=\pmatrix{-b&a\\-d&c}\;,$$

and

$$MA=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{c&d\\-a&-b}\;.$$

If these are equal, what does that tell you about $a,b,c$, and $d$? The same argument applies to $B$. Knowing the general form that $A$ and $B$ must have, try to show by actual computation that they commute.